# Python: using function from another class on class call

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to use functions from class A when you call class B without referencing them?

```
class A:

    def value(self):
        return self.value


class B:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        # load A or what ever

class C:
    first = B(1)


x = C.first.value()
>>> 1
```

Comment: Classes `A` and `B` currently have no relation to each other. You could have `B` inherit from `A`, or give `B` an instance of `A`. Without a concrete example though, it's hard to make any suggestions.

Comment: Yeah okay thats right lets handle it its like a database handler and  i want to use it on two ways.
so class A are the Querries of a database, class B is the Database one its one that i can use (so value will be the name of the database) and C is only like folder named Database. My goal is it to write the code like `Querries.find("DatabaseName", **where)` or like `Database.Databasename.find(**where)`